# How can I stretch a container vertically to max screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100.00,
          height: 100.00,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ])),
));
```

Currently, the height is 100.00, but I need to stretch it to infinity.

I tried to change the height to double.infinity:

```
Container(
          width: 100.00,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.red,
```

But then I receive the following error:

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your Container with an Expanded-Widget and remove the height completely.

```
Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: 100.00,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
```

The Expanded-Widget fills the available space of the child of a Row or a Column along the main-axis.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this, you can either:

1) Use a widget called `Expanded` widget.

```
body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ])),
));
```

2) Give the `Container` a `height` and `width` of the device screen using the `MediaQuery` class

```
body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          // give it a width equals to the device screen
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          // give it a height equals to the device screen
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ])),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to assign height to is the calculating height of

1. App Bar
2. Top Bar Space(Exist on the above App Bar)
3. Remaining screen

**Logic:**

**1. Get the MediaQuer**

```
 final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

**2. Declare the AppBar Widget and same App Bar instance should be used in Scaffold App Bar**

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Home'),
    );
```

**3. Use calculated height**

```
      Container(
              width: mediaQuery.size.width,
              height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                  appBar.preferredSize.height -
                  mediaQuery.padding.top),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
```